# Ansible Cisco Switch "Operation requires privilege escalation" *NetworkChuck Example*

Tags: python, ansible, cisco

I seem to be having an issue with creating even the most basic playbook in Ansible and I'm not sure how to fix my issue. I get the following error...

"fatal: [10.1.3.1]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: operation requires privilege escalation
fatal: [10.1.3.49]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: operation requires privilege escalation"

Below is my "ansible.cfg" file-

```
[defaults]
inventory = hosts
stdout_callback = yaml
host_key_checking = False
retry_files_enabled = False
interpreter_python = auto_silent
[persistent_connection]
connect_timeout = 60
command_timeout = 60
```

Below is my "config.yml" playbook-

```
---

- name: General Config

  hosts: Network_Devices

  tasks:

  - name: Add Banner

    ios_banner:
      banner: login
      text: |
        Nicolas Cage is the
        Tiger King
      state: present

  - name: Add loopback

    ios_interface:
      name: Loopback21
      state: present
```

And finally below is my "hosts" file-

```
[Network_Devices]

10.1.3.49
10.1.3.1


[Network_Devices:vars]

ansible_user=root
ansible_password=cisco
ansible_connection = network_cli
ansible_network_os=ios
```

Comment: It looks like you need to enable privilege escalation. See e.g. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#become-network

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that and got the error- 'unable to elevate privilege to enable mode, at prompt [None] with error: timeout value 30 seconds reached while trying to send command: b''enable'''

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with ansible from the past couple of months. Setting the "ansible_become_password" connection variable in the inventory worked for me. Source- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#become-network